# Unable to get newline character to render on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net

I'm doing some server-side validation on a sharepoint aspx page. If there are any errors, I pass a string to the zone.error text in PreRender.

**How do I get my newline characters to render?**

**Right now I have:**

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_errorText))
        {
            this.Zone.ErrorText += "I'm an error!" + Environment.NewLine + "Fix me damnit!";                
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

I have tried various combinations of

> <br />, \r\n, \n, while using htmlEncode and htmlDecode to no avail.

I have read something about <pre>,  in the past, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

What's the trick here?

Comment: maybe throw it inside a textarea box or use a line break <br /> element in html

Comment: Have you tried `<br />`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to render a `<br/>` tag not an Environment.NewLine, that will simply drop a \n or \r\n in.  That won't render on the HTML page.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_errorText))
        {
            this.Zone.ErrorText += "I'm an error<br/>Fix me damnit!";                
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. It renders the <br/> with the entity codes. It looks like it's doing an httpUtility.htmlDecode on the string first. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Ray if the control displaying the html can't be configured otherwise, then I don't think there's anything you can do.

Comment: @Ray I was assuming you were just displaying this in a label or writing it directly to the page.  If not System Down might be right.

Answer (score 1):

try to use tag

```
<br>
```

instead of Environment.NewLine